# Handle external package logs from fastapi middleware

Tags: logging, fastapi, openai-api, python-logging, fastapi-middleware

We are hitting openai api from our fastapi application, We have middleware where we format the logs to json. There are some special characters in logs , and we need to remove them before we display the logs in console.
We have special character remover function in middleware , it works perfectly for logs from application , but for logs from openai the special character is not removed.
I placed a debugger in function , and call is not coming to this function if it is from openai.

```
class FilterEmojis(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        record.msg = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', str(record.msg))
        return record




logger = logging.root
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.handlers = [handler]
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addFilter(FilterEmojis())
logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access").disabled = True
```

"level": "DEBUG", "conversation_id": "ap-1", "name": "openai", "message": "api_version=2023-07-01-preview data='{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "\\nWelcome to ai **\\ud83e\\udd16\\ud83d\\udee9\\ufe0f**"